# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header using Bing Speech in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, bing-speech

I am using Bing Speech in Chatbot using Bot Framework it was working good but today I got this error:

"https://speech.platform.bing.com/synthesize: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access."

Is this an error within platform, if so do you know if this will happen often?
Or is this error caused by some other reason?

Comment: This issue has been fixed.  If you run into other issues or bugs, that are not questions, please use the BotBuilder GitHub repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new

Comment: @EricDahlvang today also i am having same issue sometimes!!! What do you suggest ?

Comment: Please file an issue on the BotBuilder GitHub repository